# Array of custom Controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I need to create Listbox in C#/WPF which contains the following

Something which is like a multi column list box, 
One field for text, second field contains text which is to be chosen from a Combo Box.
I need to know the selection event so that I can validate the selection.
I am making a kind of mapping between two texts and the first field of text is not selectable, the second field to be selected from the combobox.

I need to put it in a box which is scrollable.

So my questions are

1. Is it possible to build such a thing using C#/WPF.
2. How do I trigger a window containing a listbox and capturing the selected item.

Lets Say

I have a signal A1, A2, A3
I need to map them to signal B1, B2, B3

So I want to show two rows of text

I want to get which signal got selected and then assign it to the correct row.

[edit]
Ok So I think it is possible to build one, I tried something with the following XAML code,
But I could not get the listbox to resize correctly and the data binding is still not Ok. Need to capture the Combobox selection too. :D

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox  Name="Mapping" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,0"                  
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source=StaticResource CanMainPageViewModel.MappingInformation}"
              >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CanMainPageViewModel.MappingInformation.SigName}" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="8"/>
                        <ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="8"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

So my problem still remains,

[EDIT]
So playing around I found this can solve my problems now

```
<UserControl x:Class="Caribou_wpf.Controls.CanMostSignalMappingControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Caribou_wpf.Controls"
         xmlns:CanMainPageViewModel="clr-
               namespace:Caribou_ViewModel.Data.CAN;assembly=Caribou_ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MappingInfoTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox  Name="Mapping" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,0"                  
        ItemsSource="{Binding CanMainPageViewModel.MappingInformation.Signals}"
              >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CanSignal.SigName}"
                              Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Top"                            
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10"/>
                        <ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="200" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" 
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MostPropertyParam}"
                                   DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                   />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

I just need to make sure that all items are ReadOnlyCollection

But somehow the controls are always sticking to the left. Can anyone point out please , why it is so.

Now how do I capture which object index is triggering the selected item in the combobox?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like a (relatively complicated) data template. Yes, you can build it. I'd answer except I'm not sure on the validation piece. The question is kind of hard to read, could you clean it up and provide a screenshot, some sample data perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it

```
    <ListBox  Name="Mapping" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,0"                   
        ItemsSource="{Binding CanMainPageViewModel.MappingInformation.Signals}"
                 BorderThickness="1"
              >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CanSignal.CompleteSignalName}" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="280" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Calibri"  
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="5,2,3,2"/> 
                        <ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="280" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Calibri" 
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MostPropertyParameters}"
                                   DisplayMemberPath="ParCompleteParamName" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3,2,5,2"
                                   SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedMostPropertyParamIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   />
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```